# Using Trait types with rust-portaudio in non-blocking mode

Tags: rust

I'm following the [sine example](https://github.com/RustAudio/rust-portaudio/blob/master/examples/sine.rs) in the rust-portaudio examples directory (which uses the non-blocking API), and I'm trying to get `run()` working with a Trait type argument instead of calculating the samples within `run()` itself.

The trait I've defined is pretty simple:

```
pub trait Evaluatable {
    fn evaluate(&mut self) -> (f32, f32);
}
```

---

I changed the `run()` function signature to the following to accept my trait:

```
fn run<E: Evaluatable + 'static>(mut generator: E) -> Result<(), pa::Error>
```

and upated the callback function to call `evaluate()` on the trait type instead of generating samples itself:

```
let callback = move |pa::OutputStreamCallbackArgs { buffer, frames, .. }| {
    let mut idx = 0;
    for _ in 0..frames {
        let samples = generator.evaluate();
        buffer[idx]   = samples.0;
        buffer[idx+1] = samples.1;
        idx += 2;
    }
    pa::Continue
};
```

`E` has to be `'static` due to this callback (see [`open_non_blocking_stream()`](https://github.com/RustAudio/rust-portaudio/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L472)), which is the main source of my frustration...

---

In `main`, I can create an `Evaluatable` type and pass it in just fine (aside: I'm surprised this works, do objects in `main` get `'static` lifetime?):

```
fn main() {
    // Implements Evaluatable
    // arguments are: sample rate, frequency, amplitude
    let mut sine_generator = SineGenerator::new(44100.0, 200.0, 0.3);

    run(sine_generator).unwrap()
}
```

But I want to be able to combine signals, so I made a struct that can combine them:

```
use evaluatable::Evaluatable;

pub struct Combine<'a> {
    first: &'a mut (Evaluatable + 'a),
    second: &'a mut (Evaluatable + 'a),
}

impl<'a> Combine<'a> {
    pub fn new(first: &'a mut Evaluatable, second: &'a mut Evaluatable) -> Combine<'a> {
        Combine {first, second}
    }
}

impl<'a> Evaluatable for Combine<'a> {
    fn evaluate(&mut self) -> (f32, f32) {
        let first_output = self.first.evaluate();
        let second_output = self.second.evaluate();


        (first_output.0 + second_output.0, first_output.1 + second_output.1)
    }
}
```

And tried to use it in `main()`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut sine_generator1 = SineGenerator::new(44100.0, 200.0, 0.3);
    let mut sine_generator2 = SineGenerator::new(44100.0, 250.0, 0.3);

    let combine = Combine::new(&mut sine_generator1, &mut sine_generator2);
    run(combine).unwrap()
}
```

Now, Rust seems to have a problem with the lifetimes not being `'static`:

```
Error[E0597]: `sine_generator1` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:37
   |
27 |     let combine = Combine::new(&mut sine_generator1, &mut sine_generator2);
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
28 |     run(combine).unwrap()
29 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

---

1. Why was Rust able to allow me to use `SineGenerator` from `main()`, but won't let me use `Combine` which takes the same objects (with, I assume, the same lifetimes)?
2. Is there a better way to implement `Combine` that will allow me to do what I want to do here? I had to take references because Trait types don't have defined size at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why was Rust able to allow me to use `SineGenerator` from `main()`, but won't let me use `Combine` which takes the same objects (with, I assume, the same lifetimes)?

A `'static` bound on a type parameter means that the type may not borrow anything that lives shorter than `'static`. Your `SineGenerator` doesn't borrow anything, so it respects that bound. `Combine`, on the other hand, doesn't respect the bound because it contains borrowed pointers, and you instantiate it with a lifetime that is shorter than `'static` by storing references to local variables in the `Combine` object.

> 2. Is there a better way to implement `Combine` that will allow me to do what I want to do here? I had to take references because Trait types don't have defined size at compile-time.

The typical solution is to use type parameters instead of trait objects.

```
pub struct Combine<F, S>
where
    F: Evaluatable,
    S: Evaluatable,
{
    first: F,
    second: S,
}

fn main() {
    let sine_generator1 = SineGenerator::new(44100.0, 200.0, 0.3);
    let sine_generator2 = SineGenerator::new(44100.0, 250.0, 0.3);

    let combine = Combine::new(sine_generator1, sine_generator2);
    run(combine).unwrap()
}
```

By having `Combine` own the `Evaluatable`s, it will respect the `'static` bound (if both `F` and `S` are `'static` themselves).

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thanks! Looks like I still have a lot of learning to do with Rust.